# Derivative at curve endpoints

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, curves, curvature

Suppose that ${\bf R}(s)$ is a curve in 3D space parameterized by arc length $s$. The curve has endpoints at $s=0$ and $s=S$. Can one give meaning to and calculate $\frac{d{\bf R}(s)}{ds}$ and $\frac{d^2{\bf R}(s)}{ds^2}$ at $s=0$ and $s=S$?

Comment: Do you know anything about $\mathbf{R}$, e.g., it is twice continuously-differentiable, or does it extend to a twice-differentiable function on an open interval containing $[0, S]$?

Comment: We can assume it is twice differentiable on $[0,S]$.